# Cómo saber si la ubicación geográfica del usuario está dentro de una zona determinada?

Tags: flutter, geolocalización

Estoy creando una app en flutter que usa la geolocalización del usuario y sólo le permite solicitar servicios determinados días de la semana en función de su ubicación dentro de la ciudad. Por ejemplo: La ciudad se divide en 2 zonas, Los usuarios de la zona 1 podrán solicitar sus servicios los días lunes, miércoles y sábado. Por otro lado, los usuarios en la zona 2 podrán solicitar servicios los días martes, jueves y domingo.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar, muchas gracias!

Comment: qué API de mapas estás usando? si es google maps API, puedes utilizar geocercas, si recuerdo bien

Comment: @L.Ronquillo La verdad no he empezado esa parte aún. Sin embargo pretendo hacerlo con google maps. Sabes de algún tutorial para poder hacerlo?

Comment: La respuesta a la pregunta del título es usando la intersección de un punto con un polígono. Hay varios algoritmos sirven para este propósito https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon. Debes buscar alguna librería que te ayude a ello.